# mysql query locking up database

Tags: php, mysql, database, locking

This query locking up(causing it to lock the metadata) database and users can't able to perform any other operations

What exactly the wrong with this query and suggest changes to the query to work well.

```
SELECT
    a.uid, p.fname, p.lname
FROM
    adt_data a
INNER JOIN
    p_data p ON a.uid = p.uid
WHERE
    a.id
IN (
    SELECT MAX( id ) 
    FROM
        adt_data
    GROUP BY
        uid, facility_id
    ORDER BY
        id DESC
)
AND
    patient_category !=3
AND
    a.uid NOT 
IN
    ( 6987 ) 
ORDER BY
    p.lname, p.fname
```

EXPLAIN SELECT MAX( id ) FROM adt_data GROUP BY pid, facility_id ORDER BY id DESC 
is returning

id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  adt_data    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    13757   Using temporary; Using filesort

rows 13757

Explain result for whole query below

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   PRIMARY     a   ALL     pid,patient_category    NULL    NULL    NULL    13757   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY     p   eq_ref  pid     pid     8   bestcaredb_19jun15.a.pid    1   
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  adt_data    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    13757   Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Comment: Run the explain plan for the query `explain select...` and share the result into the question. Also which table column is `patient_category` ?

Comment: patient_category is from adt_data table

Comment: ah yes, and Using temporary will create a temporary table. Note that you can join a table with itself `select MAX(b.id),... from adt_data a inner join adt_data b on a.uid=b.uid and a.facility_id=b.facility_id ... order by b.id DESC;` for example. Please add a quoted explain result for the whole statement too.

Comment: Added whole explain query result. but don't know how to format. please check

Comment: just quote it (4 spaces in front of each line) It's fixed font ascii output

Comment: Added quoted explain result. Please check and suggest.

Answer (score 0):

To debug table locks in mysql you should use describe or explain. And first check the results of your subquery

```
explain select MAX(id) from adt_data ...
```

This will show you how many rows are visited and if keys are indexed, which will speed up match and order operations.

#### Add a key

To add a keys, for you adt_data for example you can use

```
alter table adt_data add key facuser (uid,facility_id), add unique key id;
```

where the pair (uid,facility_id) is a non unique key, and id must be unique.

Comment: EXPLAIN SELECT MAX( id ) FROM adt_data GROUP BY pid, facility_id ORDER BY id DESC is returning

id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE adt_data ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 13757 Using temporary; Using filesort

rows 13757

Comment: you can immediately see here that all key fields return NULL, so you have no index or there is no index used for some reason to sort the adt_data table. Finding the MAX(id) thus needs to check all 13757 rows of the table for the maxmimum id. This is done in a temporary table I think and the first thing you can simply change by introducing index keys for id, uid and facility_id.

Comment: uid and facility are not be unique because user have multiple rows for the same facility. suggest me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Here how to use facuser  in query? and id field is already primary key.